# como imprimo el texto seleccionado de un select en un td y agrego ese td a una tabla ya existente

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Cordial Saludo!

[image: views1]

Que puedo implementar que no sea otro **botón** para poder capturar el valor del select seleccionado e imprimir dicho valor en otra **vista** diferente, si solo tengo un **boton** de redirigir?
nose si al alterarlo  se me cargaría la información del producto ya que esta en un ciclo por lo mismo no lo he tocado.

`<a href="<?=base_url?>carrito/add&id=<?=$product->id?>" class="button">Agregar al Carrito</a>`

este boton se encuentra en la vista **1** la cual me redirige y me carga la información de la compra en una segunda vista **2**
como se muestra a continuación:
[image: views2]

Donde dice **talla** es donde quiero que se muestre la información seleccionada en el select.
Como puedo imprimir este dato seleccionado de la vista **1**  en la vista **2** y me lo muestre en pantalla. como los demás datos.los datos están guardados en tablas distintas.

Comment: Usa un formulario, convierte el elemento ancla en un submit.

Comment: Desde otro punto de vista... ¿Y si dejas la selección de la talla en la segunda vista?. Tal como está la opción de aumentar o disminuir unidades, podrías poner el `select` con las tallas. Considera hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer las normas del sitio. Luego, te sugiero ampliar un poco más la info de tu pregunta, algo de código nos vendría bien para tratar de replicarla.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente: en el cuadro de SELECT le pones un evento change. Cuando se elija un valor el manejador del evento debe añadir al enlace del botón un nuevo get: &talla=valor seleccionado de esa manera envia a la vista 2 el artículo y la talla.

```
<select onchange="ponertalla()">
...
<a href="<?=base_url?>carrito/add&id=<?=$product->id?>**&talla=m**" **id="agregar"** class="button">Agregar al Carrito</a>
```

El valor talla debería ser añadido por la función asignada al onchange del select
Luego en el php que genera la vista 2 se lee el valor talla mediante $_GET['talla'] y lo colocas en la celda correspondiente (lo mismo que se coloca el precio y otros datos).

```
function ponertalla(){
    var o = document.getElementById('link');
    var talla = o.href;
    talla = talla.replace(/&talla=[^"]+/i, "&talla="+event.target.value);
    o.href = actual;
}
```

Es una orientación en base al poco código que pones en la pregunta. La función ponertalla() habría que refinarla como verás.
Espero que te sea útil
**EDITO**
Si prefieres usar como veo JQuery el código que pones en tu auto respuesta debes cambiarlo, el elemento seleccionado no es text() sino val(). El script de comprobación sería por tanto:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").on("change",function(){
            var valorSelect=$(this).val()
            console.log(valorSelect)
         })
            
     })
</script>
```

Esto te devuelve el campo value de la opción seleccionada

Comment: gracias por el aporte, pero no e podido hacer el evento bien.

Answer (score 0):

intente con este script pero me manda todas las opciones y necesito solo la que selecciono:

```
<select name="nav" id="select">
            <?php while ($tall = $tallas->fetch_object()): ?>
                <option value="<?= $tall->id  ? 'selected' : ''; ?>">
                    <?= $tall->nombre ?>
                </option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </select>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
              $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#select").on("change",function(){
                var valorSelect=$(this).text()
                 console.log(valorSelect)
            })
            
            })
        </script>
```